# Inner join in JPA using native query

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables -

1. Podcasts
2. Categories

Podcast columns - `podcast_id, podcast_autho, podcast_category_id, podcast_description, podcast_owner, podcast_subcategory_id, podcast_title`

Category columns - `category_id, category_name, category_owner`

`podcast_category_id` has a value from the `Categories` table and so does `podcast_subcategory_id`.

Now, I have an SQL statement which inner joins the two table to produce category name instead of id in the output -

```
SELECT p.*, c.category_name, c2.category_name AS sub_category_name FROM podcasts p 
LEFT JOIN categories c ON p.podcast_category_id = c.category_id
LEFT JOIN categories c2 ON p.podcast_subcategory_id = c2.category_id;
```

I use the same query in my `JpaRepository` class to get the output -

```
interface PodcastRepository: JpaRepository<Podcast, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT p.*, c.category_name, c2.category_name AS sub_category_name FROM podcasts p " +
            "LEFT JOIN categories c ON p.podcast_category_id = c.category_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN categories c2 ON p.podcast_subcategory_id = c2.category_id",
            nativeQuery = true)
    fun getPodcastsByOwner(owner: Long): List<Any>
}
```

I do get an output but it is not in JSON format unlike other cases where I don't user `Any` (`Object` in Java) but the specific Entity class.

What I get -

```
[
  [
    8,
    "krktush",
    2,
    "World War 1",
    1,
    3,
    "What Went Wrong",
    "General",
    "Specific"
  ],
  [
    9,
    "krktush",
    2,
    "World War 2",
    1,
    3,
    "What went right",
    "General",
    "Specific"
  ]
]
```

What I expect -

```
[
  {
    "id": 16,
    "author": "krtkush",
    "title": "World War 1",
    "description": "What Went Wrong",
    "category": "2",
    "subCategory": "",
    "owner": 1,
    "categoryName": General,
    "subCategoryName": Specific
  },
  {
    "id": 22,
    "author": "krtkush",
    "title": "World War 2",
    "description": "What Went Right",
    "category": "20",
    "subCategory": "",
    "owner": 1,
    "categoryName": General,
    "subCategoryName": Specific
  }
]
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Use a DTO to map the result instead of `List<Any>`.

Comment: Could you please provide some links or code to start from?

Comment: Just create a data class that contains the properties (and make sure the column names or aliases in the query match) and return `List<YourDto>`,